# Swagger CodeGen personalize Equals in properties

Tags: java, spring, swagger-codegen

i am working on a project that use swagger codegen, unfortunately they asked me to do a fix and I feel really stack, we have this swagger with an object, they requested me that in a specific object of the swagger when the class is generated the equals method must not check all the properties of the object and ignore one specific property, is possible so personalize the generation of the equals for a single object of swagger? for example using templates?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is using customized templates and extensions (e.g. x-skip-equal) to indicate a particular property needs extra handling.